# Is there a way to store heat?

Tags: thermodynamics

I dont have the most experience with thermodynamics, but i was wondering if it was possible to store heat, as in have some sort of battery or a mystical foucet that would just release heat when you ordered it to. This being said, the battery or foucet would not need insulation or to burn something on the inside, but it would work more as an electrical device. It's a relatively dumb question but it interests me quite a bit.

Comment: Have you ever kept hot coffee or soup in a thermos bottle?

Comment: I said without needing insulation, but would work more like a battery. Plus a thermos with coffee is not just storing the heat, but also whatever liquid or solid you have inside

Comment: 1. You can't store heat without some material to store it in. 2. You can't keep the heat from escaping that material without insulating it.

Comment: What you can do is store some other form of energy, and then convert it back to heat later.

Comment: 'Thermal mass' is a measure of heat storage, as in an adobe wall.

Comment: A pretty good storage place for thermal energy is fossil fuels.  When combusted, these release large amounts of heat.  Hey, we already do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> possible to store heat, as in have some sort of battery

Yes, in [zeolites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeolite), which store it in their internal structures. This doesn't cause them to heat up, so they don't lose this energy to the environment. They've been [considered for solar heating](http://www.sunwindenergy.com/solar-thermal/millions-new-heat-storage) because they can store the energy for a LONG time, enough to time shift summer sunlight into the winter.

Every so often someone raises the idea of using zeolites for electrical storage - sort of. One way, for instance, is to use an intermittent sources like a wind turbine to create heat and store that in the zeolite. When you want it back, you run air through it and use that to pre-heat a gas turbine.

No one's got the economics to work out yet. Tanks of heavy oils, brine or even just li-ion batteries always seem to be one step ahead.

Comment: One would need to store any dried zeolites in a zero humidity environment. Otherwise, water vapor in the air would adsorb and heat would be given off, just like a battery sitting on a shelf.

Comment: Indeed. One local effort was in big tanks in an old mine. Never went anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

> i was wondering if it was possible to store heat

Heat is not a thing that is stored. Heat is energy transferred from one system to another because of temperature differences.  It results in a loss of energy by one system and the gain of energy of another system. It is similar to work conceptually, in that we can't store work: work is the transfer of energy from one system to another via force interactions, and we separate it from heat in our "accounting" due to the models we choose to describe the transfer of energy (thermodynamic and statistical mechanics versus classical mechanics and electrodynamics).  Both work and heat are expressed in energy units, but they, themselves, are not energies to be "stored".

Also, the increase in temperature of an object doesn't mean there is more "heat" in the object. It simply means that the object has more energy than it had before (but a constant temperature doesn't necessarily mean constant energy either!). Consider a metal plate at a certain temperature. Hit it several times with a large hammer. The temperature of the metal plate will be higher, but you haven't applied any heat to the plate. You did work on the surface and the molecular structure of the plate transferred that work into internal energy which shows up as a temperature increase. (Not getting into the fine details of phonons or QM, etc.)

> This being said, the battery or foucet would not need insulation or to burn something on the inside,

So how can we store energy? We can raise the temperature of a substance, such as water or stone (in a greenhouse, for instance). We can change the phase of a substance (water into steam). We can then transport these high temperature things to another location and let them lose energy to other objects.  The problem with doing this is that higher temperature objects **always** lose energy to lower temperature objects. Insulation only slows down the process.

> but it would work more as an electrical device.

Actually the same loss principle is true of batteries. The chemicals in the batteries are always reacting and the potential energy available for electrical transfer decreasing. Manufacturers are constantly researching how to extend the storage life of batteries, i.e., to increase the effective "insulation" of the chemical potential energy.

> some sort of battery or a mystical foucet that would just release heat when you ordered it to.

There is nothing magical about getting energy from one place to another. There is always a loss, there is always work, there is always an increase in entropy.